# What is the difference between Multilevel and Multidimensional association rule

Tags: python, data-mining, group

I have read that in **Multilevel Association** rule there is abstraction present and generally the higher abstraction has higher chances of correlation.

e.g - *buys(X, "Laptop") => buys(X, "Printer")*

Note: Here X is a variable representing customers.

In **Multidimensional Association** rule there are multiple dimensions or predicates.

e.g - *age(X,"18...25") ^ occupation(X, "Student") => buys(X, "laptop")*

Note: X here is also variable.

Can some explain this with some simple practical examples?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank You for your response @D.L. I was reading this book Data Mining Concept and Techniques(3rd Edition) by Jaiwei Han in which he explained about both the terms with examples. I will share the same examples here.

Comment: it sounds like perhaps i should guide you towards my own book here:  https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0BHL2XKCR (**Python Programming: Top Of The Stack**).  . . Multilevel association rules are used to discover relationships between items or attributes that occur at different levels of abstraction in a dataset. . . multidimensional association rules are used to discover relationships between multiple attributes or dimensions of a dataset.

Comment: I would add that you should provide a reproducible code example for the purpose of how stackoverflow works. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Okay @D.L I will try to read more and understand from your book thank you.